# mvc kendo combo box loading very slowly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I have implemented a kendo combox control that populates 10,000 records. There is latency during form load as well as while selecting the comboxbox to see the list. What is the best way to tackle this performance issue. If you notice the , cascading feature is implemented for this combo. It filters based on the countrycode value from another combo.

kendo combo

```
   <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })

                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.CustomerMasterDataId)

                 .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
                .DataTextField("CustomerNumberName")
                .Placeholder("Select...")
                .DataValueField("CustomerMasterDataId")
                .Filter("contains")
                .MinLength(3)
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                      .Read(read =>
                      {
                          read.Action("RequestHeader_CustomerData", "Request")
                              .Type(HttpVerbs.Post)
                              .Data("GetSalesOfficeFilter");
                      }).ServerFiltering(true)
                                ).CascadeFrom("CountryCode").Filter("contains")

                   .Events(e =>
                   {
                       e.Change("onCustomerComboChange");
                   })
                        )
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
```

Conroller code

```
public ActionResult RequestHeader_CustomerData(string id)
        {
            var response = requestRepository.GetCustomerData(id).AsQueryable().ProjectTo<CustomerViewModel>();

            var jsonResult = Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
            return jsonResult;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You maybe sending all the records to the client -- use developers tools to see the json payload.  I don't see any criteria being passed to your action, so if there is any filtering going on, it is being done client-side (but I am not that familiar with the Kendo ServerFiltering).

Comment: Server filtering would be a great way to limit the number of items coming back from the server. [Here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/serverfiltering) is a link to the demo of the combo box server side filtering functionality.